# Android custom theme, color not changing for Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

Excuse the short question, but this seems relatively simple but can't get the toolbar color to change:

[image]

Changing the textSize or even the parent of the `ToolbarTitle` property **does** cause changes to the text, but I cannot get the color to change no matter what I try.

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:background` to your toolbar theme to change the toolbar color. [Ref](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar)

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is about the textColor, sorry I know the title says just "color". It's not turning white.

Comment: Use app:titleTextColor attribute for the Title color and app:subtitleTextColor for the Subtitle color. See details https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar